# Exchange for Comics/cartoons? - Bobs Burgers

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I posted this on the Scifi exchange as it was the closest exchange I could find but its been deemed off topic...

Is there a specific exchange for comics?

The reason is because I was wondering how many Bobs Burgers Comics there's been issued, to date; including variant/alternative covers?

I'm hoping to find/collate a list so I can collect them all.

I look forward to all info and resources you post. Thanks.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76741/cartoons

Comment: If it's about anime and manga, [anime.se] too.

Comment: @Braiam it's not unfortunately, but there are [places](https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=25985681) that you can still look for such info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there doesn't appear to be a specific exchange to which this is suited but I have been given a few links and resources. This information, together with some details I found by endless searching is summarised below:

To date, these are the known issues (including variant covers):

---

**Issue 1 :-**

1. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1A]  3. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1C]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1A** - Default Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1C** - Limited 1 for 25 Retailer Incentive Variant Cover.
2. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1B]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1B** - Blank "AUTHENTIX" Cover.
3. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D0] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D2] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D3]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D0** - 2nd Print Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D1** - 2nd Print Black & White Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D2** - 2nd Print Virgin Art Cover.
4. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D3] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D4]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D3** - 3rd Print Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1D4** - 3rd Print Virgin Art Cover.
5. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1E0] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1E1] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1E2]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1E0** - RARE Belcher Girls Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1E1** - RARE Belcher Girls Black & White Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1E2** - RARE Belcher Girls Virgin Art Cover.
6. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1F0] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1F1] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1F2]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1F0** - Baltimore Comic Con Exclusive Variant Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1F1** - Baltimore Comic Con Exclusive Variant Black & White Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1F2** - Baltimore Comic Con Exclusive Variant Virgin Art Cover.
7. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-MIDTOWN1]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-MIDTOWN1** - Midtown Comics Retailer Exclusive Variant.
8. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-MIDTOWN2] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-HASTINGS] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-SUPERFLY] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-EARTH2]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-MIDTOWN2** - Midtown Comics Retailer Exclusive Variant.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-HASTINGS** - Hastings Retailer Exclusive Variant.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-SUPERFLY** - Super-fly Retailer Exclusive Variant.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #1RE-EARTH2** - Earth2 Retailer Exclusive Variant.
   - plus many other "Beefsquatch" Retailer Exclusive Variants, such as Third Eye Comics.

---

**Issue 2 :-**

9. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #2A] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #2B]

   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #2A** - Default Cover.
   - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #2B** - Limited 1 for 25 Retailer Incentive Variant Cover.

---

**Issue 3 :-**

10. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #3A] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #3B]

    - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #3A** - Default Cover.
    - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #3B** - Limited 1 for 25 Retailer Incentive Virgin Variant Cover.

---

**Issue 4 :-**

11. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #4A] [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #4B]

    - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #4A** - Default Cover.
    - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #4B** - Limited 1 for 25 Retailer Incentive Virgin Variant  Cover.

---

**Issue 5 :-**

12. [image: Bob's Burgers (2014) #5A]

    - **Bob's Burgers (2014) #5A** - Default Cover (final issue in the first-ever miniseries).

---

I will update if necessary in the future, but I think this list is complete. Should anyone find additional variants or issues, please be sure to comment below or edit this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but one day there might be. :)

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Cartoons]